# What does "alimentarse del viento" mean?

Tags: traducción, definiciones, modismos, expresiones

If someone puts the phrase "Alimentarse del viento" as their status on a social site, what does it mean?

Comment: "Take in the breeze" .. maybe?

Comment: For me it means to don't have nothing to eat, it's just an expression. It's the way we use it in Colombia. Can you give more context?

Comment: @SergioVelásquez Yep, in Spain has the same meaning.

Comment: Yes. In Colombia, it is also usual to say (there are variations on the question): "P, ¿De que te alimentas? R. De viento molido, de aire raspado.", "Q. What are you eating? A. Grounded wind, scraped air" to mean you don't have anything to eat nor money to buy food. Or that you are fasting.

Comment: In Spain is commonly defined as "Vivir del aire", it means the same, but I've never heard "Alimentarse del viento".

Answer (score 4):

I often use it this way when traveling or going out for quite a while.

> We'll need something to eat. No one lives from wind.

Or

> Wind doesn't feed anybody.

Maybe the guy on the social site doesn't have a job or something similar.

Comment: Agreed. When someone says he doesn't want to work, a common answer is "¿Te vas a alimentar del viento?", trying to prove the point that working is pretty much mandatory